# Bootstrap height responsivity

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make a very simple responsive page. The width works fine; when I resize the window or when I display with a mobile device it is fine, but the hight doesn't work properly, specially for the textarea. 
See below the screenshot of a laptop, the height is fine
See the screenshot after resizing (similar to mobile device), the height of the page is not 100%
Any idea ?

Here is my code :

```
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
....
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
            <br>
            <img src="image.png"
            <br><hr>
            <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea   disabled class="form-control" style="height: 100%;" >
                           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....

                    </textarea>
                    <br>
                    <hr>
             </div>
        </div><!--/col-5-->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's not responsive ? Maybe show us a picture

Comment: you can see now the 2 screenshots

Comment: This link should help you to understand the percentage height problem: http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `height: 100%;` of your textarea means that your textarea will be exactly the size of your screen.

So you have to make it smaller by reducing the height, the picture and margins/paddings might take 25/30% of the screen so your should set the size at 70% approximately.

And the scrollbar appears because there is a maximum resize of the browser. I would suggest to use device mode on chrome to test it (ctrl + shift + M ).

Comment: I set to 80% and it is quite better. Thank you